# Install linux server. No USB no CD no LAN

Tags: system-installation

I need to install ubuntu server to a PC without LAN, CD-ROM and USB. I create HDD with distributive 
`cd /path/to/iso/directory/ sudo dd if=example.iso of=/dev/sdb`

Now I try to boot from this hdd. The problem is that after first steps (language, keyboard detection) Install could not mount CDROM.

Is it possible to fix this problem?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu Server are you using? Is it a current version or an old version, which is no longer supported? (I remember that some old version had the problem that you describe.)

Comment: 16.04.03 just download today

Comment: It is a current version :-) Is it the 32-bit (i386) version or 64-bit (amd64) version? -- Are two hard disk drives connected?

Comment: It is 64 both amd64 version. On PC Ubuntu 16.4 is already installed. I just need clean install of server

Comment: What computer is it (please specify brand name and model of the server)?

Comment: Have you checked with md5sum that the download was good?

Comment: Yes I check every thing. I could not provide PC specs - it is inside server box. Vendor - Transtech.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69995/discussion-between-sudodus-and-zlon).